# Second memory slot not working

Tags: memory, motherboard

I've recently tried to add a second 2GB RAM to a computer. I bought a pair of OCZ [OCZ2P8002G](http://www.ocztechnology.com/ocz-ddr2-pc2-6400-vista-performance-platinum-4gb-dual-channel.html) and added them to my BioStar [GF8200E](http://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=427) motherboard... Unfortunately Windows 7 x86 only showed 2GB available. I took a stick out and tested it in Slot 1, it worked. I took the same stick and tested it in Slot 2 and it wouldn't boot (or even reach BIOS). I put them both back in and the machine then refused to boot in the same way... weirdly.

So now I'm stuck with a machine that will only boot with one RAM stick, limited to 2GB. Very annoying.

Is my motherboard just broken? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Did you try each stick in each slot for a total of four permutations (and thus boot attempts)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the second slot is broken. Maybe there's just some dust in there (you mustn't even be able to see it). Maybe try to blow along the memory slot using compressed air to remove some dust which could be there.

Comment: Yay Nintendo Skills!

Comment: Use an old toothbrush.

Comment: Wouldn't. You will not get into the small slot and the danger of doing some mechanical damage is too high. Some air out of a can is quite safe and cleans much better.

Comment: You were right... it was broken :(

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying to update the BIOS first (if the Motherboard is not under warranty then you are taking a risk).

In the Motherboard manual it does mention:

It is recommended to use those Validated DDR2-1066 modules suggested by AMD

This RAM is not supported and most likely the issue.

the link for the PDF is not working, but I found it here:
http://www.planet3dnow.de/vbulletin/attachment.php?attachmentid=10849&d=1206139924